# Calculating permutations with SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

In standard SQL, I want to generate all the various permutations that contain a unique set. For example, how to generate unique band line-ups based on a list of band members and their role. Each lineup must contain each role once

So, given this:

```
role   |name
-------|--------
singer |dave
singer |sammy
guitar |eddie
bass   |anthony
bass   |wolfgang
drummer|alex
```

the result would be this with four possible line-ups:

```
role   |name    |lineup
-------|--------|-------
singer |dave    |1
singer |dave    |2
singer |sammy   |3
singer |sammy   |4
guitar |eddie   |1
guitar |eddie   |2
guitar |eddie   |3
guitar |eddie   |4
bass   |anthony |1
bass   |anthony |3
bass   |wolfgang|2
bass   |wolfgang|4
drummer|alex    |1
drummer|alex    |2
drummer|alex    |3
drummer|alex    |4
```

The actually use case requires the role column to be flexible. So, we can include `keyboard`, `voilin` players and then lineups would have that role.

I am testing out solutions with SQLite using cross-joins and running out of ideas. Seems like a common scheduling sort of problem. Any ideas?

Just to clarify, the result would have every combination possible. So if you run this SQLite query on the result above:

```
select distinct group_concat(name) combination from result group by lineup
```

you get four unique records

```
combination
-------------------------
dave,eddie,wolfgang,alex
dave,eddie,anthony,alex
sammy,eddie,wolfgang,alex
sammy,eddie,anthony,alex
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL lines below implement the output you want. Just a little coding in SQL environment

```
Declare @resultTable Table
(
  role nvarchar(100),
  name nvarchar(100)
)


-- Keep track of @temp1 record processing
Declare @role varchar(100)
Declare @name varchar(100)
Declare @loopCounter INT = 1

While((Select Count(*) From roleTable)>= @loopCounter)
Begin

  DECLARE @counter INT = 0;
  

  Set @role = (SELECT Top 1 role FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY role desc) AS RoNum , role FROM roleTable) AS tbl WHERE @loopCounter = RoNum)

  Set @name = (SELECT Top 1 name FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY role desc) AS RoNum , name FROM roleTable) AS tbl WHERE @loopCounter = RoNum)

  DECLARE @recordCount INT = (Select Count(*) From roleTable where role = @role)


  if(@recordCount = 1)
  begin
    
    while(@counter < 4)
      begin
        insert into @resultTable values(@role,@name)
         SET @counter = @counter + 1;
      end
  end
  else if(@recordCount = 2)
  begin
    while(@counter < 2)
      begin
        insert into @resultTable values(@role,@name)
         SET @counter = @counter + 1;
      end
  end
  else if(@recordCount = 3)
  begin
    while(@counter < 1)
      begin
        insert into @resultTable values(@role,@name)
         SET @counter = @counter + 1;
      end
  end
  else if(@recordCount = 4)
  begin
    insert into @resultTable values(@role,@name)
  end

  

  set @loopCounter = @loopCounter + 1

 
End

;WITH newTable AS (
SELECT 
t.role,
t.name, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                   PARTITION BY t.role 
                   ORDER BY role
                   ) AS [lineup]
FROM @resultTable t)
select * from newTable
order by role desc
```

output:

[image]

Comment: what about wolfgang? he should be playing bass in lineup #2 and #4

Comment: My role based database had two values, "bass" and "bass ". I just entered the correct output.

Comment: I modified the code. This code works exactly.

Comment: wolfgang isn't playing bass with dave as singer

Comment: (bass   |anthony
bass   |wolfgang) and (singer |dave
singer |sammy)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to build the combinations. First, you need to compute the number of times any role should exist in the full output. This is accomplished in the `prod` and `p` CTEs. Then, to build the actual combination output list, you need to take the value from the `p` CTE and offset each unique role count from the records in the original input table (named `lineup` in my code below) by the value from `p`:

```
with recursive s as (select row_number() over (order by (select 1)) r, role, count(*) c from lineup group by role),
     l_mod as (select row_number() over (order by (select 1)) r, l.* from lineup l),
     prod(c, v) as (
        select 1, (select s1.c from s s1 where s1.r = 1)
        union all
        select p.c+1, p.v*(select s1.c from s s1 where s1.r = p.c+1) from prod p where p.c < (select count(*) from s)
     ),
     p as (select v from prod order by c desc limit 1),
     new_l(r, role, name, b_c, l_c) as (
        select l.*, 1, (select * from p)/(select s1.c from s s1 where s1.role = l.role) from l_mod l
        union all
        select nl.r, nl.role, nl.name, nl.b_c + 1, nl.l_c from new_l nl where nl.b_c < nl.l_c 
     ),
     final_l as (select row_number() over (order by r) r1, role, name from new_l order by r)
select l.role, l.name, (select sum(l1.r1 < l.r1 and l1.role = l.role) from final_l l1)+1 from final_l l;
```

Comment: very promising. but this solution has the same problem as meysam's solution. every permutation should be generated. eddie and alex are in every lineup so that is straightforward. the two singers and two bassists mean you have 4 possible unique combos. (dave and anthony, dave and wolfgang, sammy and anthony, sammy and wolfgang). this logic results in just two combos that are repeated. (dave and wolfgang, sammy and anthony).

Comment: @swdev Does the order of the record occurrences matter? It would seem that this is the case, since you seem to be basing the rest of your combination generation on the first block of roles (singer). Can you clarify this?  Also, can you clarify how four unique combinations (dave and anthony, dave and wolfgang, sammy and anthony, sammy and wolfgang) become (dave and wolfgang, sammy and anthony)?

Comment: I tried to clarify in the Q. If you group by lineup and combine the members of each lineup. you can see if you have all the combinations. The should be four unique records if you have them all.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax1234 is correct in "You can use a recursive CTE to build the combinations". Stored procedure might also work but are not available in SQLite. Neither answer gave me all the unique combinations (maybe I didn't explain my question well). Anyway this is what I ended up using and seems to work:

```
with recursive

-- index the players in each role
players as
(
    select
        row_number() over (partition by role order by name) player_num,
        role,
        name
    from t1
),

-- index the roles
roles as
(
    select row_number() over (order by role) role_num, role, count(*) player_cnt, ln(count(*)) ln_player_cnt
    from players
    group by role
),

-- add role_num to players
players2 AS
(
    select a.*, role_num
    from players a
    join roles b on a.role=b.role
),

-- calculate running permutation count
--  ex. role#1 has 2 members, running_perm_cnt=2   (2)
--      role#2 has 1 member,  running_perm_cnt=2   (2 x 1)
--      role#3 has 5 members, running_perm_cnt=10  (2 x 1 x 5)
--      role#4 has 3 members, running_perm_cnt=30  (2 x 1 x 5 x 3)
roles2 as
(
    select *,
        round(exp(sum(ln_player_cnt) OVER (ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)),1) running_perm_cnt
    from roles
),

-- calculate roles count, permutations count and an
ttl as (
    select count(*) role_cnt, max(running_perm_cnt) perm_cnt,  max(running_perm_cnt) * count(*) ttl_cnt
    from roles2
),

-- use recursive CTE to build the permutations
perm(n,role_num,player_num,lineup) AS (
SELECT
    1,
    1,
    1,
    0
UNION ALL
SELECT
    n + 1,
    floor(n/perm_cnt)+1,
    (floor(n/(perm_cnt/running_perm_cnt)) % player_cnt) + 1,
    n % perm_cnt
FROM
    perm, ttl, roles2 c
WHERE n < ttl_cnt AND c.role_num = floor(n/perm_cnt) + 1
),

-- join permutations back to players table so we have names
select a.*, b.role, b.name
from perm a
    left outer join players2 b on a.role_num=b.role_num and a.player_num=b.player_num
```